# Are there formulae to determine close-packing polyhedra?

Tags: packing-problem, polyhedra, tessellations

Is there a formula to determine which polyhedra will tessellate in 3D without any spaces?

Comment: without any spaces?

Comment: without voids between the forms. i.e. perfectly tessellate.

Comment: Are you asking about polyhedra which close-pack by themselves, such as the cube, or do you include sets which pack together, such as the octahedron + tetrahedron?

Answer (score 3):

You can find a "survey" of information and references about space filling polyhedra here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Space-FillingPolyhedron.html

Comment: what is the point of posting links?